# Can you know if the user installs your app for the first time or if he made an update?

Tags: ios

Is is possible to know if the user made an update or a fresh install considering that I didn't  though of it before this version (so my previous version put no user default or keychain flag for me to use in my current version for checking)?

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe resource files are deleted on install.  If you have an image in your resource bundle, or perhaps you could even use the app icon, you could change the name of the image and then check for the existence of an image in the resource bundle with the old name.

Of course, I would test this first, but I think it will work